# No search results for github

Tags: search, github

When I try and search for repositories on github I get no search results. I tried common terms such as "android" and it would say `We couldn't find any repositories matching 'android'` the problem started today. Am I searching wrong? How do I search for repositories?

Comment: GitHub UI and searching questions are better for http://WebApps.StackExchange.com - But in this case the site was just down

Comment: Someone can be interesting in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49861700/search-all-git-repositories-in-a-github-organization-for-a-pattern/49864267#49864267

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Github was down few hours ago, probably they have some problems. In fact, you can see its current status [here](https://status.github.com/) and indeed, search is disabled now. Oh, and they are being DDoSed if you're curious why they were down.

Comment: In the future if a similar problem occurs should i look at status page first?

Comment: Yes, that's very nice feature.

Comment: Looking at the GitHub status is not going to work. Look at my GitHub repo [here](https://github.com/joshiayush/ai) you will not find any code files under the language section even when the GitHub status is all Okay. GitHub is not down and all systems are operational but since I created that repo I can't find code files under language section.